# 6 balls in a bag (2 red and 4 blue) and picking 3 without replacement, is probability of picking all blue higher than picking at least 1 red?

Tags: probability

I think the probability of picking all blue is higher than picking at least one red. But I can't seem to work it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\text{picking all blue}) = \dfrac{4}{6}\cdot\dfrac{3}{5}\cdot\dfrac{2}{4} = \dfrac{1}{5}$

$P(\text{picking at least one red}) = 1 - P(\text{picking all blue}) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{4}{5}$

So $P(\text{picking all blue}) < P(\text{picking at least one red})$

$\underline{Remark}:$ in probability, the following property is quite useful:

Given an event $A$,

$$P(A) = 1 - P(A^c)$$

Also when asking a question, I suggest that you write what you've tried, so it will be easier to guide you through the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go the hard way:

**Find the probability of at least 1 red ball**:

1) Compute the probability that only $1$ ball is red, first:

1. The first ball is red, the second and the third is blue: $$\frac{2}{6}*\frac{4}{5}*\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{5}$$
2. The first one is blue, the second one is red, the third one is blue:$$\frac{4}{6}*\frac{2}{5}*\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{5}$$
3. The first and the second are blue, the third one is red:
   $$\frac{4}{6}*\frac{3}{5}*\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{5}$$

The total probability to get strictly $1$ red ball is $3/5$

2) Compute the probability of picking $2$ red balls:

1. $$P(RBR)=\frac{2}{6}*\frac{4}{5}*\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{15}$$
2. $$P(BRR)=\frac{4}{6}*\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{15}$$
3. $$P(RRB)=\frac{2}{6}*\frac{1}{5}*\frac{4}{4}=\frac{1}{15}$$

The total probability to get strictly $2$ red ball is $1/5$

The probability of picking either $1$ red ball or $2$ red balls is $$\frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{5}$$

**Comment**: While the 'go the hard way' line might make you think that I'm being sarcastic, I'm rushing to assure you that I'm not. I seriously recommend (for educational purposes) putting effort in understanding why my way and @F.A.'s way give the same number. Sure, my way is hard, but it prompts you to think about many combinatorial and probabilistic things.

PS I don't think that I have to reiterate the computation of $P$ of picking 3 blue balls. If you've understood all the things above, it should be clear by now.